# How can I add this WPF Library into my WinForm App?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a WinForms app and I wonder whether I can add this wpf notification library to my WinForms project. Is it possible?

I don't know if this works or not but whenever I add this library to my project and I call any of the `show` methods I get two Errors

for instance if I call

```
Toaster.ShowError(this, message: "My Error Message!");
```

these errors popup

```
'Toaster' does not contain a definition for 'ShowError'
```

and

```
Error CS0012    The type 'Window' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

by the way the library name is netoaster which is in this link https://github.com/zachatrocity/netoaster

Answer (score 1):

You can use MessageBox.Show();

Or look if the WPF Framework can be found in: your project -> Add refference -> COM

Answer (score 1):

Go to MSDN to see a sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

I would recommend upgrading to WPF altogether.

Comment: Looking at your code I would guess that WPF library that you want to use provides some kind of controls... Like 'Toaster'. The Windows Forms host application uses an ElementHost object to host the WPF controls. And yes, you will need to references to PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, System.Xaml, WindowsBase, WindowsFormsIntegration and your library that contains the definition for the 'Toaster'. Which part are you having difficulties with?

Comment: the library is in dll how ElementHost is gonna help?

Comment: Please don't take this personal, but I am getting a feeling that you are not very proficient with C# / .NET / WPF. In this case I would highly recommend NOT trying to use a WPF control in windows forms application. You won't do it right. In case I am mistaken - you attach a DLL to your project as a reference and you will have access to controls that are implemented in this library. That's how you get past the 'Toaster' does not contain definition for 'showError'.

Comment: clearly as you can see am not experienced in WPF... but how can i resolve this because i tried every thing including adding the dll references.

Comment: I would suggest that you stick with native Windows Forms controls as though there is backward compatibility, it is not a trivial thing to implement WPF control in Windows Forms. I won't be able to help without seeing all of the solution. But then again, MSDN article does a decent job explaining it if you want t skip down to the Windows Forms section: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_2